# Weblogic managed server log monitoring

Tags: weblogic

I am facing an issue with weblogic server - GC monitor. Sometimes the application running in weblogic is not responding and get stuck. I have to restart the managed server to restore it.When checked the managed server logs , the logs is getting appended till GC monitor log as below

< weblogic.GCMonitor> << anonymous>> <> <> <1234123456795>  <83% of the total memory in the server is free.>

After that there is no logs is getting recorded. Is there any way to monitor the logs in weblogic and send email to me when the logs is not getting recorded. So that i will restart server immediately.

Comment: The `GCMonitor` is not the source of your problem. Have you checked the managed server log as well and not just the stdout log? How long does the server run before it stops responding? Is it consistently the case? Not much info to go on here.

Comment: When this issue occurs only the application URL is getting stuck. Managed server health is still showing OK. And Managed server logs is ending with the above GCmonitor log. We started having this issue once in everyweek this month. I coudnot find what is the root cause. so i am looking for some ways to monitor the managed server logs and trigger alerts before the application goes unresponsive.